# Understanding of bosons and fermions from time-dependent state in Srednicki's QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space

Recently, I am reading Srednicke's QFT by myself and just get started. In the very beginning chapter *Attempts at Relativistic Quantum Mechanics*, it says that consider a time-dependent state of the form
$$|\psi,t\rangle=\int d^3x_1\dots d^3x_n\, \psi(\mathbf{x}_1,\dots,\mathbf x_n;t)\,a^{\dagger}(\mathbf x_1)\dots a^{\dagger}(\mathbf x_n)|0\rangle
$$
(on page 13) because the creation operators commute with each other, **only the completely symmetric part of $\psi$ survives the integration in the above equation**. For the bolded part, I do not understand the reason. So far, I know that since $[a^{\dagger}(\mathbf x),a^\dagger(\mathbf{x'})]=0$, one can swap $\mathbf x$ in any $a^\dagger$ term in the above form. Then do the change of dummy variable to make the swap in the coordinate of $a^\dagger$ into the swap of $\mathbf x$ in $\psi$. Then my concern is why can one say only the symmetric part of $\psi$ can be left. I understand that if $\psi$ is replaced by a symmetric function, then the equation after swapping can be held. However, I do not understand the inverse.

Comment: From what I understand just by the equation you wrote, the "wavefunction" appearing in the integral must be symmetric (anti-symmetric) when permuting the dummy x's if the creation operators commute (anti-commute), i.e. if the creation operators are associated with bosons (fermions), for the integral not to vanish identically. Actually, I don't really understand why such a decomposition holds, unless there is a sum over n as well. What you wrote makes me a little bit sceptical. Could describe more what the "wavefunction" in the integral is? Is it supposed to be an actual wavefunction?

Comment: In Scrednicki’s book, $\psi$ is just some function of x and t.

Comment: I think I get it now. The "wavefunction", just like any function, can be decomposed into a symmetric plus an anti-symmetric part with respect to the x's. The anti-symmetric part vanishes over integration following the procedure you just described, so only the symmetric part survives.

Comment: @PanosC. I tried in this way, and I do not think this works. The reason is for a general anti-symmetric formula for a multi-valued function, it sums over all permutations on x indices together with the multiplication of the sign of permutation with a coefficient. If f=f(x,y), then asy f=1/2(f(x,y)-f(y,x)), and sym f =1/2 (f(x,y)+f(y,x)), and f=asy f + sym f. However, one can easily show that this is not true for 3-variable case.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is bugging you. If $\psi$ was antisymmetric in all its variables, then $\psi a_1^{\dagger} a_2^{\dagger} ... =0$

Comment: @Avantgarde but the thing is $\psi$ in general is not equal to the sum of symmetry + anti symmetry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand your confusion. Lets consider just this basic definition of antisymmetry of a function: $f_{\text{anti}}(x,y)= -f_{\text{anti}}(y,x)$. 
You can define this with every pair of your variables: $f_{\text{anti}}(x,y,z)= -f_{\text{anti}}(y,x,z)$ or $f_{\text{anti}}(x,y,z) = -f_{\text{anti}}(x,z,y)$ and so on.
When you integrate a symmetric function with an antisymmetric function it will give zero as we know. So you can do this with any of the variables and it will always survive the symmetric part.

I will explain it in more detail now:

The creation operators are all together symmetric in the $x_i$'s. So I will just define the symmetric creation operator for all $a$'s as: $a^\dagger_{all}$ (we include also the vacuum state into this definition, but its not necessary for the understanding of the "surviving" symmetries).

Now lets just consider a function $\psi(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which depends just on 3 variables. Extending it to more variables is no problem as you will see.

Lets now divide this function into its symmetry parts. Lets define the symmetric part in $x_1$ and $x_2$ as $S_{12}(\psi)$ and the antisymmetric part in $x_1$ and $x_2$ as $A_{12}(\psi)$. It doesn't matter how this splitting is going on...we just know that there is a symmetric and an antisymmetric part [ (this means that you must not define $S=\frac{1}{2}(f(x,y)+f(y,x)$ and $A=\frac{1}{2}(f(x,y)-f(y,x))$ ]

So lets write down the whole function $\psi$ (the dependence of the $x$'s is understood):

$$\psi=S_{12}(\psi)+A_{12}(\psi)$$

But we can split any of this parts into the symmetries of $2 \to 3$ and $1 \to 3$. Lets do it just for the symmetric part $S_{12}$...the other is done similar.

$S_{12}(\psi)=S_{12}(S_{23}(\psi))+S_{12}(A_{23}(\psi))$ (and the same  with $1 \to 3$) again. So with $n$ particles we would have to split it $n$-times into its symmetric and antisymmetric parts.

Any term which has one (or more) antisymmetric terms (say $A_{12}$ or $A_{23}$ or $A_{13}$) will vanish in the integration because the $a^{\dagger}_{\text{all}}$ is totally symmetric. So the only part which survives is $S_{12}S_{23}S_{13}$ which is the completely symmetric part of $\psi$ as Srednicki said.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will expand my understanding for a new answer. Of course, I will accept yours.

Comment: Could you have a look at my expanded solution?  I think the last step to give the total symmetry property of the final $\psi$ is not good-looking.

Comment: I wrote you now the extended answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks and yes, this is exactly what I thought. For a general case, one will leave the completely symmetric thing of $\phi$. I just have a different notation.

Answer (score 0):

According to user487344's idea. For each arbitrary pair of $x_i$ and $x_j$, the function after doing the integral of all $x_k$ except $x_i$ and $x_j$ can only leave its symmetric part, say the following function
$$\Phi(x_i,x_j)=\int d^3x_1\dots \widehat{d^3x_i}...\widehat{d^3x_j}...d^3x_n \psi(x_1,...,x_n)a^\dagger(x_1)...\widehat{a^\dagger(x_i)}...\widehat{a^\dagger(x_j)}...a^\dagger(x_n)
$$
where the wide hat means without involving the term of $x_i$ and $x_j$. As we know swapping $x_i$ and $x_j$ will not change the value of $\int d^3x_id^3x_j\Phi(x_i,x_j)a^\dagger(x_i)a^\dagger(x_j)|0\rangle$. Also, we know that for a two-variable function $f(x,y)=S f(x,y)+Af(x,y)$ where $Sf(x,y):=1/2(f(x,y)+f(y,x))$ and $Af(x,y):=1/2(f(x,y)-f(y,x))$). Then notice the symmetrization can be pull into the integration of $xs'$, this leads the remaining of $\tilde{\psi}_{ij}=2\times1/2\psi(x_1,...,_{(x_i,}...,x_k,..._{x_j)},...,x_n)$ where the subcript means to do the symmetrization on these variables,$f_{(x_i,x_j)}:=f(x_i,x_j)+f(x_j,x_i)$. Similarly, for the remaining $\tilde\psi_{ij}$ put it into the position of $\psi$ in $\Phi$ (since we know the antisymmetric part vanishes) do the same thing again and again and again until you compute all the indices. Eventually, one can obtain a $\psi$ which is totally symmetric in its coordinates.